# Can you create C like header files in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In C, you can have a header file with lots of imports. Can this be done in Flutter?

Rather than including/importing dozens of files and having to scroll down before your code even starts, you can create a header file with all of your includes, like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
.
.
.
#include "myUmteenthFile.h"
```

Instead of importing a bunch of files into the same file you put your code in, you can create a common file with all of your imports, and import that single file into your code files. It makes your code cleaner. Can this be done in Flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be done in Flutter and Dart.

You would create a library file to do this. Here is an example:

You create a file and name it however you like; here I will call it "my_imports.dart".

```dart
library my_imports;

export 'stdio.dart';
export 'stdlib.dart';
.
.
.
export 'myUmpteenthFile.dart';
```

Note: `stdio` and `stdlib` aren't dart files, I am just using the names from the C example.

You would then import this file into your code files to keep them clean and not have so many imports themselves.

Example of importing this library file:

```dart
import 'path/to/my_imports.dart';
```

Comment: Any `.dart` file is implicitly a library. You don't need the `library my_imports;` line.  Unless you're providing dartdoc documentation for the library file itself, that line redundant and potentially confusing (because then people will wonder what library name to use, whether the name matters, and what happens if the name doesn't match the filename). If necessary for dartdoc documentation, you can use a bare `library;` statement. Otherwise, I don't see any value that `library my_imports;` provides, even for readability.

Comment: @jamesdlin This is true; however, official Flutter code uses the abovementioned method. You can see it in files like `material.dart`. I like my code to match how the official developers do it. I suppose it boils down to preference.

Comment: Official Flutter code uses that most likely because it was written before the bare `library;` statement was allowed ([a relatively recent addition](https://github.com/dart-lang/dartdoc/issues/1082)).  The Flutter SDK also uses a different internal style than the recommended style from the Dart team.